# Vue computed property not updating object literal

Tags: vuejs2, computed-properties

I'm building a GeoJSON editor which displays a preview in **[vue2-google-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-google-maps)**. One of the challenges is converting the GeoJSON's `coordinates` into `LatLngLiteral`'s to be used as props in `<GmapMarker>`, `<GmapPolygon>`, or `<GmapPolyline>`. My solution is to use computed properties. So when the GeoJSON's changed, the map objects get changed too. Like so:

```
computed: {
    mapObject() {

        // If the geometry is a point, just assign geometry.coordinates into `lat` and `lng`
        if (this.$data.geometry.type === "Point") return ({
            lat: this.$data.geometry.coordinates[1],
            lng: this.$data.geometry.coordinates[0],
        });

        // If it's a polygon, grab the first set of coordinates (we aren't supporting polygons with holes for now).
        // then splice off the last element (Google Maps' polygon automatically loop the shape, unlike GeoJSON's convention),
        // then we map the values into an array of LatLngLiterals.
        if (this.$data.geometry.type === "Polygon") return this.$data.geometry.coordinates[0].splice(-1, 1).map(e => ({lat: e[1], lng: e[0]}));

        // If it's a LineString, do as above, without the splicing.
        if (this.$data.geometry.type === "LineString") return this.$data.geometry.coordinates.map(e => ({lat: e[1], lng: e[0]}));
    }
},
```

Problem is, this won't update for `Point` types. This seems to be working fine for `Polygon` and `LineString` types, though. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you updating the point?

Comment: @skirtle `this.$data.geometry` is `v-model`'d onto a subcomponent, a custom input.

Comment: Have you tried putting some console logging in `mapObject`? It might help to establish whether than function is running when you're expecting it to run, or if it is somehow returning the wrong value.

Comment: @skirtle The `if` block is executed just fine, `geometry.type` reads `Point`, the value just won't update.

Comment: If the computed function is running then the value *is* being updated. That begs the question, how are you determining that the value hasn't updated? It seems that it's something else that isn't updating, not `mapObject` itself. Something else to try: add `console.log(this)` inside the computed function and then expand the value of the `mapObject` property within the console after it should have updated.

Comment: @skirtle I added logging _outside_ the `if` blocks and I think we're getting somewhere. The `computed` doesn't execute when typing the coordinates while `geometry.type` is `Point`. Changing `geometry.type` triggers the update and so does changing coordinates when `geometry.type` is not `Point`.

Comment: That seems to suggest that the `type` property is reactive but the `coordinates` property is not. Either that or the array is being updated in a non-reactive way. That takes us right back to my original question about how you are updating the point. The custom input should be emitting a totally new object but it's starting to sound like it mutates the object it is passed. Mutating that object will likely fall foul of one of the reactivity caveats, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats or https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203070/discussion-between-starleaf1-and-skirtle).